# How to shutdown supervisor process correctly/completely?

Tags: nginx, supervisord

I am using supervisor to launch and manage a nginx process. So far this works perfectly. The problem I am having is shutting down the instance.

I have tried using "supervisorctl -c  shutdown [all]" and this shuts down the daemon and in the supervisorctl interactive console it says nginx is stopped. However, if I do a ps -A | grep nginx command it still appears in the list.

My config for the nginx instance is as follows:

```
[program:nginx]
command=./bin/nginx
    -p /home/me/sites/project.domain.com/
    -c project/etc/nginx.conf
directory=/home/me/sites/project.domain.com
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
exitcodes=0
stopsignal=TERM
```

Any suggestion why nginx could not be shutting down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure you are not starting up nginx in daemonized mode? It is [important you start all your child-processes of supervisor in non-daemonized mode](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#nondaemonizing-of-subprocesses). I currently don't have nginx boot options at hand, but this might give you a start in the right direction.

Comment: A little late, but yes, this did the trick. Processes were not being killed because they were deamonized. Thanks.